# Spark Streaming: How Spark and Kafka communication happens?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I would like to understand how the communication between the Kafka and Spark(Streaming) nodes takes place. I have the following questions.

1. If Kafka servers and Spark nodes are in two separate clusters how would be communications takes place. What are the steps need to configure them.
2. If both are in same clusters but are in different nodes, how will be communication happens.

communication i mean here is whether it is a RPC or Socket communication. I would like to understand the internal anatomy

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it doesn't count if the Kafka nodes and Spark nodes are in the same cluster or not, but they should be able to connect to each other (open ports in firewall).

There are 2 ways to read from Kafka with Spark Streaming, using the older `KafkaUtils.createStream()` API, and the newer, `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream()` method.

I don't want to get into the differences between them, that is well documented [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html) (in short, direct stream is better).

Addressing your question, how does the communication happen (internal anatomy): the best way to find out is looking at the Spark source code.

The `createStream()` API uses a set of Kafka consumers, directly from the official `org.apache.kafka` packages. These Kafka consumers have their own client called the `NetworkClient`, which you can check [here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/NetworkClient.java). In short, the `NetworkClient` uses sockets for communicating.

The `createDirectStream()` API does use the Kafka `SimpleConsumer` from the same `org.apache.kafka` package. The `SimpleConsumer` class reads from Kafka with a `java.nio.ReadableByteChannel` which is a subclass of `java.nio.SocketChannel`, so in the end it is with done with sockets as well, but a bit more indirectly using Java's Non-blocking I/O convenience APIs.

So to answer your question: it is done with sockets.

Comment: Is it possible to use synchronous communication between nodes in Spark Streaming, for example Http Requests/Responses?