# Kafka with Spark Streaming works in local but it doesn't work in Standalone mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm trying to use Spark Streaming with a very simple script like this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils


sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSparkStreamingKafka")


ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
kafkaParams = {"metadata.broker.list": "172.31.71.104:9092",
                       "auto.offset.reset": "smallest"}

training = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ["test"], kafkaParams)

training.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

But although locally it works, with the cluster using Standalone mode it crashes. I've also tried with createstream instead of createDirectStream but I still have the same issue. I have a cluster with 4 machines:

1 machine with Kafka Producer, 1 Broker and 1 Zookeeper
1 machine is the driver
2 machines are the workers.

The strange thing is that when I had Kafka Producer, Broker and Zookeeper in the same machine in which I have the driver, it worked both locally and in the cluster. But obviously for the sake of scalability and modularity I'd like to use the current configuration.

I'm using Spark 2.4.6, the Kafka Streaming API are "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.6" and the Kafka version that I'm currently using is kafka_2.11-2.4.1

The result is the following:

```
020-07-24 09:48:25,869 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 172.31.69.185, executor 0): java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:78)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:68)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.foreach(NextIterator.scala:21)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:561)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:346)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)


2020-07-24 09:48:27,174 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:153) failed in 2.943 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 172.31.79.221, executor 1): java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:78)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:68)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.foreach(NextIterator.scala:21)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:561)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:346)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)

Driver stacktrace:
2020-07-24 09:48:27,179 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:153, took 3.010820 s
2020-07-24 09:48:27,190 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1595584104000 ms.0 from job set of time 1595584104000 ms
2020-07-24 09:48:27,191 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1595584105000 ms.0 from job set of time 1595584105000 ms
2020-07-24 09:48:27,193 ERROR scheduler.JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1595584104000 ms.0
org.apache.spark.SparkException: An exception was raised by Python:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/util.py", line 68, in call
    r = self.func(t, *rdds)
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py", line 173, in takeAndPrint
    taken = rdd.take(num + 1)
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1360, in take
    res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 1069, in runJob
    sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 172.31.79.221, executor 1): java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:78)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:68)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.foreach(NextIterator.scala:21)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:561)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:346)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:153)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:78)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:68)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.foreach(NextIterator.scala:21)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:561)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:346)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)


at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.callPythonTransformFunction(PythonDStream.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.apply(PythonDStream.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:179)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:179)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-07-24 09:48:27,211 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:153
2020-07-24 09:48:27,215 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:153) with 1 output partitions
2020-07-24 09:48:27,215 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:153)
2020-07-24 09:48:27,215 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
2020-07-24 09:48:27,216 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
2020-07-24 09:48:27,216 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1 (PythonRDD[9] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:53), which has no missing parents
2020-07-24 09:48:27,220 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 6.9 KB, free 366.3 MB)
2020-07-24 09:48:27,223 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.0 KB, free 366.3 MB)
2020-07-24 09:48:27,225 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on ip-172-31-69-46.ec2.internal:41579 (size: 4.0 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
2020-07-24 09:48:27,226 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1163
2020-07-24 09:48:27,227 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (PythonRDD[9] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:53) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
2020-07-24 09:48:27,229 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 1 tasks
2020-07-24 09:48:27,230 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, 172.31.69.185, executor 0, partition 0, ANY, 7785 bytes)
2020-07-24 09:48:27,248 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 172.31.69.185:44675 (size: 4.0 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/./prova2.py", line 22, in <module>
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/context.py", line 192, in awaitTermination
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.awaitTermination.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: An exception was raised by Python:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/util.py", line 68, in call
    r = self.func(t, *rdds)
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py", line 173, in takeAndPrint
    taken = rdd.take(num + 1)
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1360, in take
    res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 1069, in runJob
    sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 172.31.79.221, executor 1): java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:78)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:68)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.foreach(NextIterator.scala:21)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:561)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:346)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:153)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:78)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:68)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.foreach(NextIterator.scala:21)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:561)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:346)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)


at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.callPythonTransformFunction(PythonDStream.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.apply(PythonDStream.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:179)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:179)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


2020-07-24 09:48:27,532 ERROR scheduler.JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1595584105000 ms.0
py4j.Py4JException: Error while sending a command.
at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:397)
at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:356)
at py4j.reflection.PythonProxyHandler.invoke(PythonProxyHandler.java:106)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.call(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.callPythonTransformFunction(PythonDStream.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.apply(PythonDStream.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:179)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:179)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: py4j.Py4JNetworkException: Error while sending a command: null response: c
```

I've debugged everything but I don't have any idea about how to solve this problem. Do you have any suggestion? It could be a Kafka configuration problem?
Thanks in advance,

Davide

Comment: Just check for the firewalls ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027963/spark-streaming-how-spark-and-kafka-communication-happens

Comment: Did you find any solutions ?